# Find the chance that subset $B$ is distributed evenly between $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$

Tags: combinatorics

We are given set $A$ which is divided to the 3 parts ($A_1$,$A_2$, $A_3$).
$|A| = n = 9k$.
For $i,j = 1,2,3;\space \forall i \ne j : A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset; \space\space |A_i| = \frac n 3$.
Partitions are equivalent with respect to the order: ($A_1$,$A_2$, $A_3$) = ($A_3$,$A_2$, $A_1$).
There is fixed set $B \subset A : |B| = \frac n 3$.
Question is to find $P(i = 1,2,3 :|B \cap A_i| = \frac n 9)$.

**Solution draft**
Would it be $\frac {{\binom {\frac n 3} {\frac n 9}}{\binom {\frac {2n} 9} {\frac n 9}}{\binom {\frac n 9}  {\frac n 9}}} 9$ ?
I really don't feel particularly confident with the combinatorics.
I would appreciate you guys take a look. Thanks!
**Edit**
Ok, Previous is false.
B is fixed and we only pick $A_i$.

Comment: We're assuming that the elements of B are chosen uniformly from the elements of A, right? As a check of the formula, for $n=9$ the probability is $1/10$ by inspection.

Comment: @SuzuHirose B is fixed, we are not choosing it.  Your check did helped, but how'd you get 1/10?  Would you take a look at my solution below?

Comment: I just drew a picture and counted the cases when $n=9$. There are three ways to have all three in one set, six ways to have two in one set and one in another, and only one way to have one in each set. Which gives 1/10 chance. I don't have a general formula.

Answer (score 0):

So, amount of all possible partitions is  $\frac {{\binom {n} {\frac n 3} } {\binom {\frac 2 3 n} {\frac n 3}}} {9}$.
Partitions we are interested in are the same, but we fix $\frac n 9$ elemets in each subset. Hence, it's:
$\frac {{\binom {n- \frac n 9} {\frac n 3 - \frac n 9} } {\binom {\frac 2 3 n - \frac {2n} 9} {\frac n 3 - \frac n 9}}} {9}$.
Then probability is: $$ \frac {{\binom {n- \frac n 9} {\frac n 3 - \frac n 9} } {\binom {\frac 2 3 n - \frac {2n} 9} {\frac n 3 - \frac n 9}}} {{\binom {n} {\frac n 3} } {\binom {\frac 2 3 n} {\frac n 3}}} $$